# Error when trying to write data to Excel sheet using Fillo API

Tags: java, excel, jdbc, apache-poi

I have a DB installed in my system. I have a "users" table with 2 columns: Username & Password. 
I'm using JDBC connection to retrieve values from the DB.
I'm using Fillo API to write the values to excel sheet.

However, after the file writing is completed, when i open excel sheet, i find out that Fillo writes the data in an unusual way:

```
Username               Password



User1
User2
User3
                        Pwd1
                        Pwd2
                        Pwd3
```

Clearly, there are some empty rows at beginning, and the data for "password" is not aligned with "username". I need the data to look like:

```
Username                Password
User1                   Pwd1
User2                   Pwd2
User3                   Pwd3
```

My Fillo API code:

```
Fillo f = new Fillo();
com.codoid.products.fillo.Connection c = f.getConnection("C:\\Users\\Test.xlsx");
```

//write "user1" to excel sheet.

```
String myQuery1 = "INSERT INTO "users"(username) VALUES('user1')";
c.executeUpdate(myQuery);
```

//write all "password" to excel sheet.

```
String myQuery2 = "INSERT INTO "users"(password) VALUES('pwd1')";
c.executeUpdate(myQuery);
```

What's wrong in the code? Would appreciate answers which uses Fillo API to resolve this.
Or else, Apache POI API answers will also be excepted.

Comment: An insert creates a new row, so that each insert creates a new row is fully expected. If you want values in the same row, you should use `INSERT INTO "users" (username, password) values ('user1', 'pwd1')` or something similar instead.